# Debugging error 1064 in SQL in order to see what's failing on a long SQL statment

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I am running a SQL command that is very large. I am getting error 1064 (Syntax error or access violation).

Is there any way to get the prepared statement, to see where the fault can be? I'm only seeing 50 characters and I honestly don't know what the bug could be.

This is how I create and prepare the statement:

```php
function insertIntoMultiple($tablename, $columns, $data, $datetime_column_name = 'created_at') {
    global $db;
    
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode($data), true);
    $exp = explode(", ", $columns);
    $params = array_diff($exp, ["created_at"]);
    $real_columns = join(",", $params);

    // $join = join(',', json_decode($columns, true));
    $query = "INSERT INTO $tablename ($real_columns, $datetime_column_name) ";
    $i = 0;
    $c = count($data);
    foreach ($data as $param) {
        $marks = getMarks($params);

        // $query = storeQuery("INSERT INTO $tablename ($join, $datetime_column_name) VALUES ($marks, NOW())");
        $query .= "VALUES ($marks, NOW())";
        $query .= $i < $c - 1 ? "," : ";";
        $query .= "\n";

        ++$i;
    }

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $pars = getParams($data, $params);

    $r = $stmt->execute($pars);

    return $r;
}
```

Where there are 24 columns and 1000 values to insert. So there is 24,000 parameters on the query.

These are the methods which I use in order to create the string for the query:

```php
function getMarks($params, $for_update = false) {
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        if($param == "created_at") continue;
        $arr[] = $for_update ? '$param = ?' : '?';
    }
    return join(',', $arr);
}

function getParams($params, $columns) {
    $arr = array();

    foreach ($params as $param) {
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            if($column == "created_at") continue;
            $arr[] = $param[$column];
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

For some reason, this isn't working and this is the unique output that I'm getting:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
> error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
> the right syntax to use near 'VALUES
> ('1','xxx','xxxx7010','','https://xxxx/xxx/5...' at line 2 in
> /root/project/php/api.php:126

As you can see I can't manage to make it to work with this unique information.

I already saw this question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3817760/3286975

And I did the following code to output the entire command to a string:

```php
function pdo_debugStrParams($stmt) {
    ob_start();
    $stmt->debugDumpParams();
    $r = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    
    return $r;
}
```

Which gives me the same query (with the marks), because I suppose that this needs to be called after the `->execute()` method which is giving me an exception, so I can't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of
`$query = "INSERT INTO $tablename ($real_columns, $datetime_column_name) ";`

Use this
`$query = "INSERT INTO $tablename ($real_columns, $datetime_column_name) VALUES";`

And also replace this line `$query .= "VALUES ($marks, NOW())";`

with `$query .= "($marks, NOW())";`

Comment: Yep, I didn't see it. Thanks!